# BMC Remedy application Testing using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Do you have automated BMC remedy application using Selenium Web Driver? I am facing many issues while identifying the Objects. Browser based issues, events not working, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

I personally found selenium to be very unreliable in any case.
Therefore I recommend to use [XLT](http://www.xceptance.com/products/xlt/what-is-xlt.html), which is free for Testing, they charge only for loadtesting.
If you have good connections to BMC, you might try their own BMC TMArt Product, but that is going more into monitoring instead of testing...